# How to estimate the probability of a scenario in general

Tags: probability

For my finance lecture we are currently on the topic of operation risk.

Scenarios play a vital role in the estimation of low frequency (or probability), high impact (or severity) events.  How could you estimate the probability of a scenario?

This question is 2 marks, but would a step in the right direction be finding an appropriate distribution for frequency and severity of events.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particularly fascinating area of inference, at least in my opinion.  While you are asking for an estimation of the probability of an unlikely event, I'll instead offer a paper that presents a heuristic for detection of model error.  It is explicitly probability free.

[Mathematical Definition, Mapping, and Detection of (Anti)Fragility](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1208/1208.1189.pdf)

Taleb has spent the majority of his professional life dealing with so-called "Black Swan Events" (a term he popularized with his book "The Black Swan").

To the point, finding an appropriate distribution of low frequency events is a particularly troublesome task that does not fit nicely into classical statistical inference.  Those events go to the heart of Hume's problem of induction, a topic that Taleb seems to have devoted his professional life to.